Filter records by subdocument array
I am using findOne() to filter record base on the field of the nested subdocument but findOne() and find() are returning all the records instead of filtering it by the subdocument field.
WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE
I want to return the records that match only the subdocument field used in the query filter.
WHAT I HAVE TRIED
RETURN DATA
  "importedBooks": {
      "_id": "674ed7fd61f952ddf3e4a661",
      "stakeholder": "stakeholder",
      "book_code": "test",
      "book_name": "Germain Marine Inc.",            
      "book_details": [
        {
          "isbn": "723936122",
          "shipper_name": "Timothy Lee",
          "user1": "ABC",
          "user2": "CDE",
          "user3": "FGH",          
        }
        ....
      ],

QUERY 1
const importedBooks = await Book.findOne({
  $and: [{ _id: "674ed7fd61f952ddf3e4a661" }, { "book_details.user2": "CDE" }],
});

QUERY 2
const importedBooks = await Book.findOne({
  $and: [{ _id: "674ed7fd61f952ddf3e4a661" }, { "book_details.user2": "CDE" }],
}).select({
  book_details: {
    $elemMatch: {
      user2,
    },
  },
});

Query 1 worked but returned all the records in the subdocuments(user1, user2, user3) rather than just user2 but QUERY 2 did not work at all as it showed syntax error saying that "user2" is not defined(user2 that is referenced in the $elemMatch). I actually wanted to use aggregate but I am populating records from other Models with the find() and findOne() but I do not know how to populate fields from other Model with aggregation.
All the examples i have been seeing are using MongoDB but not Mongoose.
I will appreciate your kind assistance.

Thank you for the edit @Vinayak Vohra
